# Extracting a subset from a data set (names) in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a list of students and associated data in rows (exam grades broken down by problem). I would like to check this against a list of students in my section (roughly 1/4 of them) and extract only those rows. A solution in either google sheets or excel is fine.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mark your students on the list and apply a filter.

Comment: If you already have a section column, filtering by that would be simplest. If you only have a list of student names in your section, you could also create a column of those in a constants sheet, and then add a new column to `vlookup` against that. Then, filter on that column, including the row only if the lookup was successful.

Comment: Could you show some sample screenshots?